# Backup Strategy for array configurations

Tags: storage, storage-area-network, clariion

Are there any backup strategies for array configurations for Clariion, Cellera, Centera, and Symmetrix?

Comment: You want a backup of the array configuration only? Not the data on the arrays?

Comment: yes, only for the array configuration...does EMC have any way to carry out ,I would also like to know how it is done on the fabric side as well...thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Clariions don't have config files the only way to restore your configuration would be to recreate it from your log files (i.e. getall, getlun). If you configure your Clariions via CLI scripts, saving them in order you can replay this back to restore config.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you do an SP collect and download that it should have all the LUN configs in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can back up and restore the bin files from the service processor on Symmetrix.

Answer (score 0):

For Symmetrix provision GKs to a backup host with SYMCLI (Solutions Enabler). Schedule a job that'll log and rotate the following:

```
symaudit list
symevent list
symmaskdb -file <...> backup
symaccess -file <...> backup
```